# What does this terminal message mean?

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, router

I can't get internet on one of my computers.  It says connected.  I had this similar problem on my other computer and I used this command to fix it:

```
ip route add default via defaultgatewayip
```

It gives me this message:

```
RTNETLINK answers:file exists.
```

And doesn't give me connectivity.  What can I do and what does this 
message mean?

Comment: This might help: http://blog.karssen.org/2013/03/28/solving-rtnetlink-answers-file-exists-when-running-ifup/

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `route`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already a default route for this gateway

Example:

1. No default route

   ```
   % route
   Kernel IP routing table
   Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
   link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
   192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
   ```
2. Add a route

   ```
   % sudo ip route add default via 192.168.2.1

   % route
   Kernel IP routing table
   Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
   default         fritz.box       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
   link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
   192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
   ```
3. Add the route again

   ```
   % sudo ip route add default via 192.168.2.1
   RTNETLINK answers: File exists
   ```

   As you can see, here is your error message.